# Why can I not cast numbers into strings in my deck of cards?

Tags: python

So I have been starting work on a deck of cards for a school project, so I have to follow along with the process of making a deck using these for loops. I tried to cast all numbers from 2 to 10 as strings so that I can create their cards:

```
suits = ["♥", "♦", "♣", "♠"]
deck = []

for suit in suits:
    for card in range(1,14):
        if card == 1:
            deck.append("A" + suit)
        elif card == 11:
            deck.append("J" + suit)
        elif card == 12:
            deck.append("Q" + suit)
        elif card == 13:
            deck.append("K" + suit)
        else:
            str(card)
            deck.append(card + suit)
print (deck)
```

however, I have an error which goes as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(removed for privacy reasons)", line 16, in <module>
    deck.append(card + suit)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Can anybody explain what I did wrong?

I was expecting an output which goes:

`[A♥, 2♥, 3♥, 4♥, 5♥, 6♥, 7♥, 8♥, 9♥, 10♥, J♥, Q♥, K♥, A♦, 2♦, etc etc etc]`

Answer (score 2):

You aren't storing the casted string anywhere at this line `str(card)`.

Updated your code to

```
suits = ["♥", "♦", "♣", "♠"]
deck = []

for suit in suits:
    for card in range(1,14):
        if card == 1:
            deck.append("A" + suit)
        elif card == 11:
            deck.append("J" + suit)
        elif card == 12:
            deck.append("Q" + suit)
        elif card == 13:
            deck.append("K" + suit)
        else:
            card = str(card)
            deck.append(card + suit)
print (deck)
```

It outputs

```
['A♥', '2♥', '3♥', '4♥', '5♥', '6♥', '7♥', '8♥', '9♥', '10♥', 'J♥', 'Q♥', 'K♥', 'A♦', '2♦', '3♦', '4♦', '5♦', '6♦', '7♦', '8♦', '9♦', '10♦', 'J♦', 'Q♦', 'K♦', 'A♣', '2♣', '3♣', '4♣', '5♣', '6♣', '7♣', '8♣', '9♣', '10♣', 'J♣', 'Q♣', 'K♣', 'A♠', '2♠', '3♠', '4♠', '5♠', '6♠', '7♠', '8♠', '9♠', '10♠', 'J♠', 'Q♠', 'K♠']
```

Comment: `deck.append(f"{card}{suit}")` is shorter and just as clear.

Comment: I agree @TimRoberts, just wanted to minimize edits so that it'll be easier to understand for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate the conditional checks and make the code more compact with judicious use of a dictionary as follows:

```
suits = ["♥", "♦", "♣", "♠"]
deck = []
hcards = {
    1: 'A',
    11: 'J',
    12: 'Q',
    13: 'K'
}

for suit in suits:
    for card in range(1, 14):
        deck.append(f'{hcards.get(card, card)}{suit}')

print(deck)
```

**Output:**

```
['A♥', '2♥', '3♥', '4♥', '5♥', '6♥', '7♥', '8♥', '9♥', '10♥', 'J♥', 'Q♥', 'K♥', 'A♦', '2♦', '3♦', '4♦', '5♦', '6♦', '7♦', '8♦', '9♦', '10♦', 'J♦', 'Q♦', 'K♦', 'A♣', '2♣', '3♣', '4♣', '5♣', '6♣', '7♣', '8♣', '9♣', '10♣', 'J♣', 'Q♣', 'K♣', 'A♠', '2♠', '3♠', '4♠', '5♠', '6♠', '7♠', '8♠', '9♠', '10♠', 'J♠', 'Q♠', 'K♠']
```